# How to add filter for categories in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

There is a category of goods Sale. It is empty. There are no items added through the admin panel. When we go to the Sale category, it dynamically populates the products with special price. As to this category to apply filter? For example color, size. Please help.

Comment: Follow this link please :   https://kb.magenting.com/content/13/60/en/magento-is-anchor-option-in-category-properties.html

Comment: This example http://joxi.ru/82QQLxRI1eDdK2. http://joxi.ru/LmGendYCRV4pbA and http://joxi.ru/bmozJ8DsMBNQEr

Answer (score 0):

Try this it filters from root category

```
$_rootcatID = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();

$_testproductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $_rootcatID))
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$_testproductCollection->load();

foreach($_testproductCollection as $_testproduct){ 
    echo $this->htmlEscape($_testproduct->getName())."<br/>"; 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function addProductPrices(Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract $collection)
{
    $collection->addMinimalPrice();
    $collection->addFinalPrice();
    return $this;
}

public function addProductSaleFilter(Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract $collection)
{
    $this->addProductPrices($collection);
    $collection->getSelect()->where('final_price < price');
    return $this;
}
```

protected function _getProductCollection(){....

```
        if(Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId() == 87){// 87 - id sale category

            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            Mage::getSingleton('elegante/product_price')->addProductSaleFilter($collection);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSiteFilterToCollection($collection);

            $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        }
```

In the front-end are not displayed filter. Where I made a mistake? Please see comment to the question, there is links to images.